# CMAKE does not define the CYGWIN variable

Tags: cmake, cygwin

I am using cmake on a cygwin console under Windows 7 64 bit. However the cmake variable *CYGWIN* (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CYGWIN.html) is undefined. Am I missing something?

For example, here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
message("CYGWIN: ${CYGWIN}")
message("CMAKE SYSTEM: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
project ( foo CXX)
```

I lauch the cygwin console and do:

```
cmake path/to/my/CMakeLists.txt
```

Selected Output:

```
>    CYGWIN: 
>    CMAKE SYSTEM:
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
> 
>    ( a warning about the WIN32 variable not being defined by cmake anymore)
> 
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -- works
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -- works
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /foo/directory
```

Configuration:

- uname CYGWIN_NT-6.1
- cmake version 3.3.2 (CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

Comment: What happens if you move them *after* the `project()` command? CMake sets up most of its internal stuff as part of `project()`.

Comment: If I move them after the project() command, it works, thanks! But then it's too late for me, as I want to specify the compilers for CYGWIN before calling project().

Comment: Normally, specifying compilers should be the job of the one who runs CMake (the user or a script), not of the project. CMake should be run from an environment already configured for building.

Comment: I want to propose a default toolchain file for compiling under Cygwin. Is this possible, even if it's a bad policy?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CMake's cross-compiling facilities, so I cannot comment on this, I am afraid.

Comment: It's a different question, so I'll close this one with your answer, and ask a new one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *CYGWIN* cmake variable is defined by the `project()` command. Moving it before the `message` commands solves the problem.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(foo CXX)
message("CYGWIN: ${CYGWIN}")
message("CMAKE SYSTEM: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
```

Relevant Output:

```
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
>    (a lot of talking)
>    CYGWIN: 1
>    CMAKE SYSTEM: CYGWIN
```